# How to copy Excel formula across row so cell reference row increments and cell reference column stays fixed

Tags: excel, reference, formula

When I copy this formula across a row of cells, cell reference row stays fixed while cell reference column increments. How do I do the inverse (column stays fixed while row increments)?

`=HYPERLINK("#vba_function()", A1)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of direct reference you can use `INDEX` function:

```
=HYPERLINK("#vba_function()",INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN(A1),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to `A1` to `$A1` in your formula and drag downwards